# MySQL join statement syntax error for ordering results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to pull down results from two tables in the same DB using a specific column (using a JOIN) and then sorted by a specific column in one of the two tables. The problem is in the second half of my statement - I don't see how to specify which table and column I want to sort on.

```
SELECT * FROM general_assessment INNER JOIN location_info USING (general_id) ORDER FROM location_info BY timestamp desc limit 0,1
```

I can't seem to get the syntax on the `ORDER` part correct.  I know I can't just specify `ORDER BY` because it'll be ambiguous without specify the table first.  How do I do I ORDER BY table and the column that I want?

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM location_info BY timestamp desc limit 0,1' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\pip\testing\tim\results.php on line 22
```

Comment: @u_mulder, that doesn't work either (already tried that). `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM location_info ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 0,1' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\Dropbox\pip\testing\tim\results.php on line 22`

Comment: ORDER BY table.field, so `ORDER BY location_info.timestamp`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: @u_mulder, did you see the answer on how to do this? the posted documentation was also a big help

Comment: Not sure why this on hold - "simple typographical error" - nope it was a syntax error in which you had to know that you needed tablename.columnname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple and did not require "ORDER or FROM" just needed a joining `.`

```
SELECT * FROM general_assessment INNER JOIN location_info USING (general_id) ORDER BY location_info.timestamp desc limit 0,1";
```